# nextgen gallery: slow image loading - jquery cycle 

Tags: jquery-cycle, nextgen-gallery

I have been using nextgen gallery of wordpress, which uses jquery cycle. 
I noticed that the images load in a lazy way (eg the gallery has 15 images, and at first only three load, then 2-3 more etc). The thing is that I create thumbnails of them so I need them to load instantly. 
Does anyone knows which code should I mess with in order to make change this behaviour?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the nextGen Gallery javascript wrapper on jQuery Cycle. 
If anyone needs to modify this, s/he should mess with the ngg.slideshow.min.js.